# Magento: how to add description at the bottom of the page

Tags: admin

My boss wants me to do this SEO activity: 
if you see this example site:

http://it.dawanda.com/borse/

and you go at the bottom of the page, you can read a formatted description of the chosen product. My boss wants me to do the same for another site, so that Google can easily index it and I am supposed to use Magento. For example, the picture below shows Magento admin page:

[image: magento admin page of the site]

For each category I should add a footer block as in example site I've just linked. I don't know where to put my hands in this page. Thanks

Comment: So you want an extra attribute for categories that you can add the SEO text in and display that on the category page? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's what my boss wants. Can you explain me? :(

Answer (score 2):

To add a category attribute create a custom module, documentation on how to do that you can find [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643).

Now add an installer script that adds the attribute:

`install-[version].php`

```
$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup();

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'description_bottom', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Description Bottom',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Now in the categories `view.phtml` (`app/design/frontend/[package]/[template]/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`) or any other place you like you can call the attribute

```
<?php if($descriptionBottom=$_category->getDescriptionBottom()): ?>
    <div class="category-description-bottom std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $descriptionBottom, 'description_bottom') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I'm not allowed to pur my hands in the code. I can only use the magento front ent application, the one I have showed in the picture enclosed in my post. Do you know it?

Comment: I mean, I have created a new block with its id and its content and now I would like to show it. I've selected "show static block and product" but the block is put at the top of the page while I want it to be showed in the footer...

Comment: The options in the screenshot are not native Magento so we'll need to know what kind of module it is. The name and vendor. But I would say it's gonna be pretty impossible to do this without code